# How do I turn off redirect to mobile pages in SAP Hybris

Tags: redirect, mobile, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a Hybris installation and my team has developed everything in the Desktop version of all the pages/tags/fragments/views.

Now my CSS Team says that they can handle the responsiveness via CSS but the Desktop version needs to be the page to be called.

My Problem is that when i open the site in mobile/emulator, the mobile paths to pages are called, finally returning a 404.

What can be done to turn this auto redirect feature off..??

Any ideas..?

I have checked the hmc and turned off channel for the Mobile, but that is only for electronics and apparels.

I am working on the b2c telco channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
# Disables the mobile version of the site. This can be made site specific like this:
# uiexperience.level.supported.b2ctelco=DESKTOP
uiexperience.level.supported=DESKTOP
```

To the project.properties file of your storefront extension.

It tells Hybris that you only want to support the desktop ui experience level.
N.B. You will need to clear the cache/cookies on your mobile device before the change will take effect.

Answer (score 1):

First it's not an auto-redirect it's how InternalResourceViewResolver is implemented within Hybris, and if you want to get rid of this functionality you can update "com.yourAcceleratorPackahe.storefront.web.view.UiExperienceViewResolver" :

```
public String getViewName(final UiExperienceLevel uiExperienceLevel, String viewName)
{
    final String prefix = getUiExperienceViewPrefix().get(uiExperienceLevel);
    if (prefix != null)
    {
        if (viewName.startsWith(AbstractPageController.PAGE_ROOT + "addon:"))
        {
            viewName = viewName.replace(AbstractPageController.PAGE_ROOT + "addon:", "addon:"); // ...pages/addon:/<extension-name>/.../<component-view>....->....addon:/<extension-name>/.../<component-view>
        }

        if (viewName.startsWith("addon:"))
        {
            viewName = viewName.replace("addon:", ""); // ................................addon:/<extension-name>/cms/<component-view>....->..../<extension-name>/cms/<component-view>
            viewName = viewName.substring(1, viewName.length()); // ....................../<extension-name>/cms/<component-view>..........->....<extension-name>/cms/<component-view>
            final String extensionName = viewName.substring(0, viewName.indexOf('/')); // <extension-name>/cms/<component-view>...........->....<extension-name>
            viewName = viewName.substring(viewName.indexOf('/'), viewName.length()); // ..<extension-name>/cms/<component-view>...........->..../cms/<component-view>
            return getAddOnPrefix() + "/" + extensionName + "/" + prefix + viewName; // ..<addon-prefix>/<extension-name>/<ui-prefix>/cms/<component-view>
        }
        return prefix + viewName;
    }
    return getUnknownUiExperiencePrefix() + viewName;
}
```

I would configure the 'youStoreFrontExtension/web/webroot/WEB-INF/config/spring-mvc-config.xml' file this way :

```
<property name="uiExperienceViewPrefix">
    <map>
        <entry key="DESKTOP" value="${commerceservices.default.desktop.ui.experience:desktop}/"/>
        <entry key="MOBILE" value="${commerceservices.default.mobile.ui.experience:desktop}/"/>
    </map>
</property>
<property name="unknownUiExperiencePrefix" value="${commerceservices.default.desktop.ui.experience:desktop}/"/>
```

With you local.properties like this:

```
commerceservices.default.desktop.ui.experience=desktop
commerceservices.default.mobile.ui.experience=desktop
```

Under recent versions of the accelerator you have a responsive view folder, if it's the one you are using you should change desktop to responsive.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism of redirection is implemented via the view resolver of spirngMVC you should find it on `spring-mvc-config.xml` file under your front extension.

To turn off redirect you should :

1. Open the file and look for the bean with id viewResolver and
2. change `uiExperienceViewPrefix` property to

   ```
             <property name="uiExperienceViewPrefix">
                   <map>
                       <entry key="DESKTOP" value="desktop/"/>
                       <entry key="MOBILE" value="desktop/"/>
                   </map>
               </property>
   ```

This will redirect all mobile views to desktop jsp pages .

El jaoujat

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the hybris wiki you should check the following URL:

https://wiki.hybris.com/display/forum/Turning+off+mobile+site+ui+experience